# Print elements of a list in a 10x10 table

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to print the 100 elements of a LinkedList in a 10 x 10 table. I have the following code:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    System.out.print(lList.get(a) + " ");
}//end for
System.out.println("");

for (int a = 10; a < 20; a++) {
    System.out.print(lList.get(a) + " ");
}//end for
System.out.println("");

for (int a = 20; a < 30; a++) {
    System.out.print(lList.get(a) + " ");
}//end for
System.out.println("");

for (int a = 30; a < 40; a++) {
    System.out.print(lList.get(a) + " ");
}//end for
System.out.println("");

for (int a = 40; a < 50; a++) {
    System.out.print(lList.get(a) + " ");
}// end for
System.out.println("");

for (int a = 50; a < 60; a++) {
    System.out.print(lList.get(a) + " ");
}// end for
System.out.println("");

for (int a = 60; a < 70; a++) {
    System.out.print(lList.get(a) + " ");
}// end for
System.out.println("");

for (int a = 70; a < 80; a++) {
    System.out.print(lList.get(a) + " ");
}// end for
System.out.println("");

for (int a = 80; a < 90; a++) {
    System.out.print(lList.get(a) + " ");
}// end for
System.out.println("");

for (int a = 90; a < 100; a++) {
    System.out.print(lList.get(a) + " ");
}// end for
```

But obviously its way too much, and not practical at all. I have been playing with this for hours trying to simplify this into a for loop or something that would change this into a few lines max, but haven't been able to figure it out. Any suggestions for a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
    System.out.print(lList.get(a) + " ");
    if ((a > 0) && (a % 10) == 0))
        System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: That works! The only thing is that it prints 11 items on the first row, and 9 on the last.

Comment: @xTopShelfx Hope u can fix that ;-) Please accept the answer in case it helped!

Comment: It definitely helps, I'm am just stuck on figuring out how to change those last rows!